# How to find out when a "example.NAME" domain was registered on?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois

I am attempting to obtain the registry records of a `.name` domain - I have tried using [who.is](http://who.is) to obtain details of whom has registered this practical domain and when was it created and when will it expire however when using this whois checker I do not get any results.

How can you get the whois information from `.name` domains.

Answer (score 1):

You're find the problem is with the whois checker your using, no all online whois checkers work with all domain types so its a matter of finding one that does.

I can confirm that both [*GoDaddy's Whois Checker*](http://who.godaddy.com/) and [Verisign's Checker](https://whois.nic.name/DotNameWhois/pages/Query.jspx) works with the `.name` domain types.

It's worth mentioning that a lot of sites use 'linux' whois command to query the domain for this information - it seems that .name is not supported using whois within linux as this results display similar to your problem:

```
Bybe@Megatron:~# whois webspell.name
Domain Name ID: 2889641DOMAIN-NAME
Domain Name: WEBSPELL.NAME
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
```

So again only certain whois checkers will work with the .name extension.

Answer (score 1):

Verisign [operates](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-names/name/index.xhtml) the `.name` gTLD.

The official WHOIS service for `.name` can be found at **http://whois.nic.name/**.

Note that second level (`example.name`) and third level (`example.example.name`) domains can be registered.

Trivia: the `.name` WHOIS service was once requiring fees: [wired.com: Dot-Name Becomes Cybercrime Haven](http://www.wired.com/politics/security/news/2007/09/dot_name)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that most whois lookup tools or websites are not sending the correct command the the .NAME whois server (whois.nic.name).

If you connect to `whois.nic.name:43` and issue `?`, you get these instructions:

```
  domain verisign.name
  nameserver A4.NSTLD.COM
  nameserver 2809:BC0:6CD:0:0:0:0:9
  registrar Network Solutions Inc.
   = ibm.name
  fu ibm.name
  full ibm.name
  sum ibm.name
  summary ibm.name
  det contact 21_CONTACT_NAME-VRSN
  contact T095710112264390
  email TEST@TESTDOM66.NAME
  ext blocked TEVA.PHARMACEUTICALS.NAME
```

So the correct command to send to the whois server is to send: `full example.com` , where example.com is replaced with the domain name.

If you were to use the `whois` command on Linux, then you should execute:

```
whois -h whois.nic.name 'full example.com'
```

I have taken this into consideration when building my whois lookup tool at https://gwhois.org/ .

Example: https://gwhois.org/google.name

[image: screenshot]